# how to get the next coming seven days in my listbox and remove the others?

Tags: c#

so far i did that but it doesnt work instead of getting me the specific date it erase all the list items please help

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<RentalCar> listBox1snew = new List<RentalCar>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1s.Count; i++)
    {
        if ((DateTime.Now.Day - listBox1s[i].WOF.Day) <= 7)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Insert(0, listBox1snew[i]);

        }
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = listBox1snew;//add car to listbox
}
```

Comment: Debug through that loop - the `if` condition is probably always false. Figure out why. Hint: `Day` probably doesn't do what you _expect_ it to do, in particular around month start/end.

Comment: Very confused now. `listBox1snew` is initialized but it is empty. Then you use a `listBox1s` that we don't know what is. Finally you try to insert something in a `listBox1` from an empty Listbox1snew. Could you explain better your code above? Possibly rename these variables to a understandable names?

Comment: i would like to get the date for the next 7 days

Answer (score 1):

First of all your logic to check for the date should be:

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(listBox1s[i].WOF).Days <= 7
```

You're setting the ListBox datasource to listBox1snew but you're never **Adding** anything to listBox1snew!

Answer (score 1):

```
listBox1.Items.Insert(0, listBox1snew[i]);
```

This makes no sense. `listBox1snew` is *empty*. I believe you meant `listBox1s[i]`.

```
listBox1.DataSource = listBox1snew;
```

This makes even less sense. First, you're inserting items in `listBox1.Items` and then you override the `DataSource`, effectively ignoring the `Items`. Also, you didn't modify `listBox1snew` in any way, so it will *still be empty*!

What I *think* you're after:

- Copy elements from `listBox1s` to `listBox1snew`.
- Set the `DataSource` to `listBox1snew`.

That would look like:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<RentalCar> listBox1snew = new List<RentalCar>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1s.Count; i++)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(listBox1s[i].WOF).Days <= 7)
        {
            // Copy from listBox1s to listBox1snew
            listBox1new.Add(listBox1s[i]);
        }
    }
    // Use listBox1new as new data source
    listBox1.DataSource = listBox1new;
}
```

Also, you could easily express this filter with LINQ:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.DataSource = listBox1s.Where(x => DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.WOF).Days <= 7).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) <= listBox1s[i].WOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subtract the two days first then find days difference.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<RentalCar> listBox1snew = new List<RentalCar>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1s.Count; i++)
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - listBox1s[i].WOF).Days <= 7)
            {
                listBox1snew .Items.Insert(0, listBox1s[i]);

            }
        }
        listBox1.DataSource = listBox1snew;//add car to listbox
    }
```